# Is there a way in sqlite to insert exact value as the primary key or other default value while inserting fresh values in a column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I believe that the row must be first be created as to get a self increment PK. Then i could replace the one column with PK value generated . But i am not getting the proper result.

```
insert = "insert into table(name, status) values (:Name, :Status)
params = {'Name': Jack,
          'status' : active
         }
db.execute(insert, params)
db.commit()
insert_type = "replace into table (type) values (select id from table)"
db.execute(insert_type)
db.commit()
```

so the table does have columns as id(auto increment ), name, status and type(default 0 or id)
Insert primary key column value to Non Primary key column in same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`last_insert_rowid()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) to get the `rowid` of the row that was just inserted. For example your second query could be :

```
update mytable set type = id where id = last_insert_rowid()
```

This only work if the update if executed right after the insert and no other thread is modifying the db at the same time.

Another solution could be to set `type` to `null` (either as default or in the inserted values) then use `coalesce(type, id)` in the queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use DEFUALT = blank to create a defualt value for any column.

Comment: thanks for participation. yes default is already done . i needed to know about other part